# Odds ratio for continuous variable

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio

I have a question

> How would you interpret the odds ratios for a continuous variable?

Comment: It might help if you clarified the context. It seems like you're talking about a continuous predictor in logistic regression (as I've assumed in the answer below) but more information would be helpful. I have the same comment regarding your interaction question - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22036/interaction-terms-interpretation

Answer (score 10):

It's not completely clear from your question, but I'm assuming you're talking about the situation where you have a single binary response $Y$ and a continuous predictor $X$ and fit a logistic regression model:

$$ \log \left( \frac{ P(Y_{i}=1|X_{i}) }{P(Y_{i}=0|X_{i})} \right) = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} X_{i} $$

Then the odds ratio, $e^{\beta_{1}}$, is the odds ratio associated with a one unit increase in $X$.

Essentially you can think of it as the odds ratio between $Y$ and the dummy variable $B$ defined such that $B=1$ if $X=x+1$ and $B=0$ if $X=x$.

**Note:** The assumption underlying the logistic model is that this odds ratio does not depend on $x$.